# how to rotate a rectangle in swing with KeyListener only once and no to do it again

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I have a rectangle in which I wanted to rotate. So I just made it that it switches the width and the height every time I press a key. But that key also moves the rectangle downwards, so after clicking again it rotates back to its former position.

So I want to know how I can make it only rotate once and the then after that if press downwards(the key which makes it rotate) again it just moves downwards but doesn't rotate it again.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class paint extends JLabel implements KeyListener {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int velocity = 20;
    int w = 200;
    int h = 100;
    int temp;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        repaint();

    }
    //this is the section i am talking about.
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            y += velocity;
            System.out.println(y);
            //the next three lines rotate the rectangle
            temp = w;
            w = h;
            h = temp;

            if (y > 261) {
                y = 1;
            }

        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            x += velocity;
            System.out.println(x);
            if (x > 591) {
                x = 1;
            }

        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            x -= velocity;
            System.out.println(x);
            if (x < 1) {
                x = 591;
            }

        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            y -= velocity;
            System.out.println(y);
            if (y < 1) {
                y = 271;

            }
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Use a "direction" or "angle" flag

Comment: 1) Don't use a JLabel for custom painting. Use a JPanel or JComponent. 2) Don't set the background in the painting method. Just invoke the setBackground(...) method when you create the component. 3) Don't invoke repaint() in the painting method. 4) Class names should start with an upper case character. 5) Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and basic examples to get you started.

Comment: And [Use key bindings instead of `KeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)